# How can I add icon into ngx-bootstrap accordion-group heading?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, accordion, ngx-bootstrap

Using ngx-bootstrap, how can I add an icon to accordion-group heading?
For example:

`<accordion-group heading="<i class='fa fa-users'></i> Users">
    This content is straight in the template. 
</accordion-group>`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think it can be done like this..

```
<accordion-group #group>
    <span accordion-heading>
      <i class='fa fa-users'></i> Users
    </span>
    This content is straight in the template. 
</accordion-group>
```

Answer (score 2):

**You can set font awesome icon with below way.**

```
<accordion-group [isOpen]="false" #accGroup>
  <button class="btn btn-light float-right">
    <i class="fa" [ngClass]="{'fa-arrow-down': accGroup?.isOpen, 'fa-arrow-up': !accGroup?.isOpen}"></i>
  </button>
</accordion-group>
```